# Grep only first octect of a subnet

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a list of subnets in a file for eg:

```
2.1.1.0/24
2.2.2.0/24
21.2.2.0/24
24.5.7.0/24
22.6.7.0/24
224.25.75.0/24
```

How can I grep and get the output only of the subnet having first octet 2. The desired output should be

```
2.1.1.0/24
2.2.2.0/24
```

I tried to use `cat file | grep '^2'` but still I couldnt get the output as above. I get the whole file back.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to match the literal `.`.  Try `'^2\.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep '^2\>' input_file
2.1.1.0/24
2.2.2.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you match the first octet as a whole, not a part of it.

Since octets are separated with dots, you need to match a dot after `2`.

You may use either `\.` or `[.]` to match a literal dot in the regex pattern:

```bash
grep '^2[.]' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/eEstZ1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='2.1.1.0/24
2.2.2.0/24
21.2.2.0/24
24.5.7.0/24
22.6.7.0/24
224.25.75.0/24'
grep '^2[.]' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
2.1.1.0/24
2.2.2.0/24
```